# Question about the Taylor formula and its applications

Tags: analysis, taylor-expansion

My author isn't too specific about a certain variable in the expression of the Taylor formula, $u$.

$$ f(x) = T_{n}(x) + (x-a)^{n+1} \int^{1}_{0} \frac{(1-u)^{n}}{n!} f^{(n+1)}[a+u(x-a)] \, du $$

My guess is that the integral is related to the radius of convergence, such that it computes the additional area/volume required to make the approximation complete.

I'm struggling to determine where this integral comes from, whether the limits he has written are always between $0$ and $1$, for all $n$, and where and how "$u$" is introduced in Taylor approximation.

Also, how is this applied to obtain the power series for transcendent functions such as:

$$ \sin(x) := \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!} $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It simply comes from **integration by parts**:

\begin{align*}
  \int_{a}^{x} \frac{(x-t)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} f^{(n)}(t) \, dt &=
  \left[ -\frac{(x-t)^{n}}{n!} f^{(n)}(t) \right]_{a}^{x}+
  \int_{a}^{x} \frac{(x-t)^{n}}{n!} f^{(n+1)}(t) \, dt  \\
  &= \frac{(x-a)^{n}}{n!} f^{(n)}(a)+
     \int_{a}^{x} \frac{(x-t)^{n}}{n!} f^{(n+1)}(t) \, dt \\
\end{align*}

Since $\displaystyle f(x) = f(a)+\int_{a}^{x} f'(t) \, dt \, ,\,$ 
by induction on $n$ and letting 
$\displaystyle u=\frac{t-a}{x-a}$ it follows that

> \begin{align*}
>   f(x) &=
>   \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{(x-a)^{k}}{k!} f^{(k)}(a)+
>   \int_{a}^{x} \frac{(x-t)^{n}}{n!} f^{(n+1)}(t) \, dt \\
>   &= \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{(x-a)^{k}}{k!} f^{(k)}(a)+
>   (x-a)^{n+1} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{(1-u)^{n}}{n!} f^{(n+1)}[a+u(x-a)] \, du
> \end{align*}

**Applications:**

We can estimate the error bound of the Taylor series using **mean value theorem**:

$$R_{n} = \frac{(x-a)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!} f^{(n+1)} (\xi)$$
for some $a<\xi <b$.